# Large title label not showing in view controller iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller, ios11

I have a table view controller embedded in a navigation controller what is embedded in a split view controller as detail view controller, I set prefers large titles from code and set both the large and the small titles font also from code (tried to remove these but did not help). Sometimes the large title does not appear. When I scroll, the small one appears. Tried to jump back and forth between the master and the detail view controller and sometimes the large title appears sometimes not. The problem only shows on iPhone.

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", size: AppDelegate.LARGE_TITLE_FONT)!]
```